# credit card form validation using Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 for credit card form validation. i have found one directive using angular1. But how do i convert this directive to angular 2.

```
<ion-input type="text" card-number></ion-input>

angular.module('app').directive
  ( 'cardNumber'
  , function(){
      var directive =
        { require: 'ngModel'
        , link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value){
              scope.ccinfo.type =
                (/^5[1-5]/.test(value)) ? "mastercard"
                : (/^4/.test(value)) ? "visa"
                : (/^3[47]/.test(value)) ? 'amex'
                : (/^6011|65|64[4-9]|622(1(2[6-9]|[3-9]\d)|[2-8]\d{2}|9([01]\d|2[0-5]))/.test(value)) ? 'discover'
                : undefined
              ctrl.$setValidity('invalid',!!scope.ccinfo.type)
              return value
            })
          }
        }
      return directive
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator

```
class CCValidator {
  validate(c:Control) {
    var valid = checkCC(c.value); // code to check the validity of the number
    if(!valid) {
      return {invalidCC: true};
    }    
  }
}

// component with a cc input field
@Component()
class MyCmp {

  form: ControlGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new ControlGroup({
      ccNumber: new Control('', new CCValidator().validate)),
    });
  }
}
```

See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html for more details